# How to skip a piece of code if a timeout expired

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am coding a simple discord bot, using discord.js. I was making a "kick" command, in which, if the user doesn't send "confirm" in x seconds, the entire command is cancelled. The problem is that i have no idea on how to set the timeout. How can i skip some code if a timeout expires?

Comment: so this isnt much information you got us but you can probably save the timestamp at the start and check at some point or regularly if the differnece is higher than x if you wnat to interrupt running code youre probably out of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: if by confirm you mean confirm(); command you cannot cancel it from running or run another code while confirm is active since confirm(); is blocking. In such case I would advise checking non-blocking methods.

```
//Declare a global boolean variable
var expired=false;
function expireIt(){
    expired=true;
}
//x seconds
//three secs for this example
let x=3000;
setTimeout(expireIt(), x);

function whateverYouRun(){
//if expired is true do nothing
if(expired){
//do nothing, time expired
}else{
//your code goes here
}
}
```

Comment: oO so I was wondering that ui for basic Auth can you abort that if you cancel the request from the backend side

Comment: Sorry, I know Node.js but I currently don't know about authentication.

Comment: yeah no it was jsut an idea ^^ It also goes quite far into dev ops thematic which i found most frontend devs dont like too muhc (sample size 4)

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much what I was trying to achieve... Thanks!